# Script to choose editor to open file based on the argument

Tags: bash, scripting

I'd like to run my script `fastex` with two possible arguments (`g` or `t`), like `fastex g`.

Based on the argument I want to call `geany $file` or `texstudio $file`. This is to choose the editor.

I tried

```
editor=$1
if ["$1" = "g"]; then
geany "$file".tex
exit 1
else
linha=$(wc -l < "$file".tex)
texstudio --line $linha  "$file".tex
exit 1
fi
```

but the outuput of `fastex.sh g` is `/usr/bin/fastex.sh: 31: [g: not found` and it always opens `texstudio`. The same if I pass `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need space after `if [` because `[` is actually a command (like `test`) which reads it's arguments (it may be interpreted by the shell but it may be not). Using `[[` makes sure shell's internal logic is used (faster, since no new process is launched). Although shells may interpret the `[` and `test` as builtins, this feature can be turned off with `enable` (and then a new process really is launched).
2. `=` is the comparison operator **inside** of conditional expressions (both external and builtin) however, it is also the assignment operator elsewhere. While `test` and `=` conform to POSIX, using `==` (recognized in `[[`) seems to be a reasonable choice whenever one doesn't aspire to POSIX conformance, since it brings a bit more sanity to the shell inconsistency of the context dependent meaning of `=`.
3. `exit 1` - why effectively discard editor's return value? Either leave it out completely or use `exec` to replace the script with the editor.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
editor=$1
if [[ "$1" == "g" ]]; then
    exec geany "$file.tex"
else
    linha=$(wc -l < "$file.tex")
    exec texstudio --line $linha  "$file.tex"
fi
```

Comment: Great. I don't know why since I am new on this, but I replaced `/bin/sh` by `/bin/bash` as you wrote and your code now works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually. `[` does take `=`; there is no such thing as assignment re `[`.

Comment: I downvoted because `1.` is false, and `==` is not even defined by POSIX.

Comment: @sigur - that code will not work in `dash`. It uses non-POSIX features (`[[`), so `/bin/sh` is not right.

Comment: @jordanm, sorry but I have no comments to you since I know nothing about this. But anyway, I'm following the great discussion here.

Comment: @Christopher, I don't know but if I use `sh` I got the error `/usr/bin/fastex.sh: 29: [[: not found`.

Comment: @Sigur actually I had a typo there, it should have been `#!/bin/bash` - just as Christopher pointed out.

Comment: @peterph - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @jordanm thanks - I've realized meanwhile what man page to check for `[`. :)

Comment: (1) “Using `[[` makes sure shell's internal logic is used (faster, since no new process is launched).” It's not a bad idea to recommend `[[`, but “faster, since no process is launched” is wrong. All modern non-embedded shells have `[` as a builtin. (2) is completely wrong, `=` is a comparison operator in both `[` and `[[` (`[[` also allows `==` as a synonym).

Comment: @Gilles 1) right, but builtins may be disabled, 2) corrected, thanks.

Comment: thanks to all for pointing out my mistakes caused mainly by my personal opinions about how shell is broken in some ways (and not researching deeper enough).

Comment: While it's true that the `[` builtin can be disabled, it's completely irrelevant that it's possible, because it isn't done in this script, and there is no reason why anyone would do so.

Comment: @Gilles yes, but only `[[` makes sure you get the builtin. People do interesting things sometimes. :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if ["$1" = "g"]; then
> ```

You need spaces inside `[` and `]`, as they are parsed like ordinary commands. Indeed, `[` is an ordinary command (which is a builtin in most shells).

> ```
> exit 1
> ```

Why are you exiting with an error status after running the editor? A return status of 0 means success, anything else means failure. You should make your script return the same status as the editor. As written, you can leave off `exit` altogether: when the shell reaches the end of the script, it terminates the execution of the script and returns the status of the last command that was executed.

As a refinement, you can use the [`exec` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec) so that instead of running the editor as a subprocess, your script will terminate and be replaced by the editor. (The same process keeps running, but its code switches to that of the other program.) But don't do that if you make this a function and not a script!

A `case` construct would be clearer to express that you're basing your conditional on the value of a particular variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
editor=$1 file=$2
case "$editor" in
  g) exec geany "$file".tex;;
  *)
    linha=$(wc -l < "$file".tex)
    exec texstudio --line "$linha" "$file.tex";;
esac
```

Comment: When I call the script it works, that is, the editor opens the file. But the terminal is locked to other commands. Is it possible to continue using the same terminal while the editor is open?

Comment: @Sigur Either run `fastex g somefile &`, or add a `&` (and don't put `exec`) on the line that launches the editor, e.g. `g) geany "$file.tex" & ;;`

Comment: Is it necessary the double quotes around the variable `$file` which was defined by `file=fastex-temp.tex`?

Comment: @Sigur If you know that the variable doesn't contain any whitespace character or any of `\[?*` (and you haven't changed `IFS`) then the double quotes aren't necessary. But you can hardly know that in advance when writing the script, so why leave them out?